# Mostrar resultado de uma lista do servlet em pagina JSP

Tags: java, html, hibernate, java-ee, jsp

Preciso capturar um nome do input, fazer a consulta no banco de dados e retornar o resultado em uma pagina jsp.
Eu quero mostrar o resultado em um pequeno trecho da pagina JSP, no caso misturar o texto da pagina JSP com o resultado que quero capturar.

**Pagina jsp com o input**

```
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" />
<br/>
Cpf: <input type="text" name="cpf" />
<br/>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
<input type="reset" name="limpar" value="Limpar" />

</form>
</div>

</body>
```

**Lista**

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

 SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
 Session session = factory.openSession();
 session.beginTransaction();

 List<Pessoa> listForm = new ArrayList<>();

 listForm = session.createQuery("from Pessoa where cpf like '%"+cpf+"%' and nome like '%"+nome+"%'").list();

 int tamanho = listForm.size();

 for(int i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
     Pessoa pessoa = listForm.get(i);
     out.println(pessoa.getId()+" - "+ pessoa.getNome());

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A partir do objeto HttpServletRequest, você pode recuperar a session e adicionar os atributos que desejar exibir na view.

Por Exemplo:(Servlet)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) {

    List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();

    request.getSession().setAttribute("nomes", nomes);
    response.sendRedirect("/view");
}
```

Para exibir os atributos na view, é uma boa prática neste caso, usar EL(Expression Language) e JSTL(JSP Standard Tag Library).

Para usar JSTL você deve baixar o jar e adicionar dentro da pasta lib ou adicionar a dependência no pom.xml caso use maven.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

Na sua JSP você deve importar a biblioteca JSTL

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

E por fim, para mostrar a lista do exemplo na view, podemos combinar el e jstl.

```
 <ul>
     <c:forEach items="${nomes}" var="nome">
         <li> ${nome} </li>
     </c:forEach>
 </ul>
```

Links Úteis

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.html
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjddd/index.html